# RXJS Subject's value not updated on reloading page

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing

I have created a service which has a subject named **selectedNode**. I am trying to update the value of subject when I gives direct URL for loading a page. The issue is that the value of **Subject** is not updated when I tries to update the value directly when passing the URL.

e.g. if I opens URL `localhost:4200/blog/page/subpage` it should update selectedNode with value `page/subpage`. But, it does not.

My code is as below:

```
blog.component.ts

import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BlogService} from '../../services/blog.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog',
  templateUrl: './blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog.component.css']
})
export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private blogService: BlogService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let routerURL = this.router.url;
    routerURL = routerURL.replace('/blog/', '');
    console.log(routerURL);
    this.blogService.selectedNode.next(routerURL);
  }
}
```

Here the below code does not update the SelectedNode Subject. I checked while debug. The value is not updated in Subject despite of routerURL has a different value and the  `this.blogService.selectedNode.next(routerURL);` is also called.

my blog.service.ts file is as follows:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class BlogService {

  public selectedNode: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  public sideNavDisabled: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getTreeNodes() {
    return this.http.get('/assets/tree.json');
  }

  public getPageContent(page: string) {
    return this.http.get('/assets/TreeStructure/' + page + '.html');
  }
}
```

My complete code is present at https://github.com/vibhorgoyal18/atest-blog
and can be viewed on https://stackblitz.com/github/vibhorgoyal18/atest-blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for putting your code in stackblitz. This helped me understand the problem a lot faster! That is the reason I upvoted, and am answering your question.

> The issue is that the value of Subject is not updated when I tries to update the value directly when passing the URL.

It *is* in fact updated. To prove this, replace the `ngOnInit` method of `BlogComponent` with the following code:

```
    const routerURL = this.router.url;
    this.blogService.selectedNode.subscribe(console.log); // console.log is called here
    this.blogService.selectedNode.next(routerURL);
```

The problem arises from the fact that **the subscriptions are not initiated before the `Subject`'s`next` method is called**. The components that are subscribing to the `Subject` aren't instantiated before this method is called.

If you want to emit a value to a `Subject` and have it's *future* observables get that value regardless of what is subscribed to to the `Subject` at the time of emission, have a look at the [`ReplaySubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/ReplaySubject.js~ReplaySubject.html)

Before taking a look at`ReplaySubject`s though, it is good to understand the difference between hot and cold observables: Subjects are 'hot' observables, which mean they fire regardless of what is subscribed to them. On the contrary, 'cold' observables are they fired dependent of what is subscribed to them. See [here](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very helpful.

Comment: @VIBHORGOYAL Why did you unlike my answer?

Comment: I am sorry if I have unliked it mistakenly. I have marked your answer as accepted answer. Your answer is also showing green tick. I am not able to understand wbat you mean by unliking an answer.

Comment: @VIBHORGOYAL My bad, I though you had downvoted but you hadn't